# Plain & Grouped UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a theoretical question. 
Why do we usually use Plain UITableViewCell styles for Dynamic lists, and Grouped UITableViewCell styles for Static ones?

Answer (score 1):

The choice of table view style has nothing to do with whether it is dynamic or static. It's a simple matter of how you want the table view to look.

If you want a list of data similar to the Contacts app, you use the plain style.

If you want grouped data similar to the Settings app, you use the grouped style.

It just so happens that when your table view is a list of data and you choose the plain style to best represent that data, it is common that the data is dynamic. But it is not unheard of to show static data in plain style.

And when you choose a grouped style to represent something similar to the Settings app, it is common that the rows you are showing in that style happen to be fixed. But it is perfectly fine to have dynamic data shown in groups.